# redirect all to another url except specific folder(s) and subdomain(s)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

presently I have my htaccess redirecting everything to another URL, unless it is in the forums folder...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/Forum
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301]
```

I have set up a sub-domain in my original site, using a folder called subdomain.

what I would like to do is retain my existing redirect, and prevent redirects of my subdomain

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to combine your !/Forum condition with a new one, as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(Forum|subdomain)
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301]
```

That uses a regular expression which will match either "/Forum" *or* "/subdomain".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement following rules should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^/subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Forum [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.newsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

R=301 will redirect with https status 301

L will make last rule

NC is for ignore (no) case comparison